# Text going out of div

Tags: css

Text going out of the div.Nothing I have tried seems to work.Example the word red going out of the div.

I have 2 divs floating next to each other shown with green and red borders.Div 1 has images coming from a databse. Div 2 which I have named #index wraps around div class='board' blue border as shown in the image,which holds the description coming from MYSQL database.

[image]

Code on index.php:

```
 <div id="index">
 <?php
 $select = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 0,20";
 $query = mysqli_query ($conn,$select);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
 $B = $row['Brand']; $P = $row['Product']; $D = $row['Description'];
 $M = $row['Model'];$Id = $row['Id'];
 echo "<div class='board' style='word-wrap: break-word;'><a href =   
 'redirect.php?id=$Id'><h2>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
 ".$B."&nbsp".$P."&nbsp".wordwrap($D,28,"<br>\n",TRUE)."&nbsp".$M."</h2>
 </a></div>"; 
 }
 ?>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #index { 
          border:solid 1px red;
          position:relative;
          float:left;
          width:59%;
          height:100%;
          word-wrap:break-word;
 }

 div.board {
              width:480px;
 }

 .board {  
          background:white;
          position:relative;
          border-radius:15px;
          border-color:#0033FF;
          border-width:2px;
          border-style:solid;         
          margin-top:31px;
          width:480px;
          height:195px;
          padding-left:0px;
          margin-left:0px;
          word-wrap:break-word;
          white-space:normal;
  }
```

Comment: Try adding a 10px padding left and right on the `.board` element

Comment: We don't care about your php. Show the HTML

Comment: It's highly preferred that you create a fiddle of the broken code instead of just describing how your code is setup.

Comment: I recreated your code with all the information present and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/uLfsyejh/

Comment: Please post all the css and html. it's difficult to try to fix with so little information. The fix has to be done somewhere else in the css. It works fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/v27cwqp6/

Comment: @AlexARH if I add padding left it places the text in the div but the text does not line up.It also widens the div which looks out of balance on the page.

Comment: @Alexei Sorry I'm a beginner and I'm not sure how to get to place my code into jsfiddle

Comment: you copy the code that's not working on your end, and paste into jsfiddle, save it then send us the link

Comment: Wrap the text in a span with a auto width and add 10px padding left/right to the span, should work

Comment: try : `.board h2 { margin: 31px auto 0 atuo;}`

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsb3x698/) it has 15px left padding and 10px right padding and no extra top padding

Comment: just add padding left to the `.board`, the reason is your text on 2nd line is not aligned with the 1st line is that **the `<h2>` tag has extra &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; in it. remove those &nbsp; and it will align perfectly**

Comment: (OP, your answer has been deleted, since it just showed the finished app, but not what the solution was. Please do add an answer with the solutions, that would be very good! Thanks.)

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin: re your earlier comment, a JSFiddle _in addition_ to presenting all the information in the question is fine. If however the information is not placed in the question, an external pasteboard is not sufficient, as links break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <div id="index">
  <?php
  $select = "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 0,20";
  $query = mysqli_query ($conn,$select);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
  $B = $row['Brand']; $P = $row['Product']; $D = $row['Description'];
  $M = $row['Model'];$Id = $row['Id'];
  echo "<div class='board' ><a href = 'redirect.php?id=$Id'>   
  <h2>".$B."&nbsp".$P."&nbsp".$D."&nbsp".$M."</h2></a></div>"; 
                                        }
  ?>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #index { 
           position:relative;
           top:15px;
           float:left;
           width:482px;
           height:100%;
    }

 .board {  
      background:white;
      position:relative;
      border-radius:15px;
      border-color:#0033FF;
      border-width:1px;
      border-style:solid;       
      margin-top:29px;
      height:198px;
      padding-left:18px;
      padding-right:0px;
      margin-left:0px;
      float:left;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```